# How to run event on RadGridView CheckBox column click

Tags: winforms, telerik, telerik-grid

I am facing a little problem with a RadGridView for Telerik WinForms. When I click on the RadGridView CheckBox column I want to run some code, but when I click on the RadGridView CheckBox column, no event is attached or run.

I achieved the same functionality in WinForms DataGridView on CellContentClick but I am unable to achieve this in RadGridView. I did a workaround with the OnKeyPress event when I press enter from the keyboard. But when I click on the RadGridView CheckBox column the code must run that time.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change a check box value in RadGridView, the ValueChanged event is triggered. However, the cell value will actually not be changed, until you click on another row/cell. If you need to immediately change the cell value, [this article](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-editors-howto-checkboxeditor-submit-value-change.html) explains how to do that.